# Why is my code not displaying the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a program that reads integers until the user enters a 0, which stores the integers and then returns the sum of integers. But its not displaying the output, what went wrong?

```
def readList():
    n=int(input())
    while n!=0:
        n=int(input())
        return n

def calSum(n):
    n=myList


myList = readList()
sum = calSum(myList)
print(sum)
```

Comment: may be you need to `return` value from `calSum` function.

Comment: I think code is not complete...

Comment: now i have got it right def readList():
    myList = []
    n=int(input())
    while n!=0:
        myList.append(n)
        n=int(input())
    return myList

def calSum(n):
    return sum(n)

n = readList()
sum = calSum(n)
print(sum)

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for

The `readList` function appends to a list and then returns the list, as apposed to return just the first number as it was doing previously.

The `calcSum` function uses Python's built-in `sum` function to calculate the sum of all the integers in the list.

```
def readList():
    myList = []
    n=int(input())
    while n!=0:
        n=int(input())
        myList.append(n)
    return myList

def calSum(n):
    return sum(n)

myList = readList()
sum = calSum(myList)
print(sum)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

calSum was assigning myList to n, but it was INSIDE the calSum and anything OUTSIDE this def was unable to read it, as it is local variable.

Same thing about n from readList. It's local. So "n" in readList and "n" in calSum does not exist outside those functions and can not be used anywhere else.

You were able to use "n" from readList, only because you used return, which returned this value to the rest of the program. And in the very same way you have to make in in calSum to make it work.

Google for global and local variables in python for more information on topic :)

```
def readList():
    n=int(input("Input from readList"))
    while n!=0:
        n=int(input("Looped input from readList"))
        return n

def calSum(n):
    n=myList
    return n #Added return as student suggested 

myList = readList()
sum = calSum(myList)
print(sum)
```